# How to use slice two times in a row

Tags: javascript

So I want to extract the year of a date but something strange happens, when I try to use two time .slice() in a row...

So here a two examples:

```
CdDate = 10.8.2021

CdDate.slice( CdDate.indexOf(".") + 1, CdDate.length )
```

expected output: 8.2021

actual output: 8.2021

everything ok...

```
CdDate.slice( CdDate.indexOf(".") + 1, CdDate.length ).slice( CdDate.indexOf(".") + 1, CdDate.length )
```

expected output: 2021

actual output: 021

...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to slice with index of the original string, you can pass from index in the index of function or maybe regex is better

This is the code:

```js
CdDate.slice(
  CdDate.indexOf(".") + 1,
).slice(
  CdDate.length - CdDate.indexOf(".") - 1 - CdDate.indexOf(".", CdDate.indexOf(".") + 1),
)
```

Comment: Thanks again XD I've searched for this a lot XD